# How to add/delete languages from android phone?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung, samsung-galaxy-y

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a new language?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/how-do-i-add-a-new-language)

I want to deleted some installed languages from android phone and also add some languages to android phone. How this can be done?

(android 2.3.6)