# Can I install additional languages on Android?

Tags: languages, localization, htc-sensation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a new language?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/how-do-i-add-a-new-language)

I bought my HTC Sensation abroad, and I can only choose system languages from the Asian region (English for different regions, as well as Chinese and Thai). I'd like to set the system language to Spanish, but it's not on the list.

Is there a way I can install additional languages to the system?

My phone is an HTC Sensation, recently upgraded to Android 4.0.5.

Answer (score 4):

Just search on the Google Play store for "custom locale",
there are a couple of apps that will allow you to install a LOT of languages.

I tried many times on different devices and Android versions, sometimes some menus or apps do not change the language, but on average it's OK.

**Example applications in Play store:**

- [MoreLocale 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale&feature=search_result)
- [Set Locale and Language](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bruce.setlocale&feature=also_installed#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwNCwiY29tLmJydWNlLnNldGxvY2FsZSJd)

But there are many more...

Comment: Can you provide a working Play store link with an app you found to be working?

Comment: The second link is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search revealed what I was expecting. It seems it's not that easy to add a new language to the OS if it's not done by the manufacturer.

So best thing you could hope for is an update by HTC. Manufacturers often install software kids on top of the android shipped out by Google.

If this is not an option installing different keyboard applications and Region Setter might help you for specific application but nevertheless the system screens remain untouched.

For a fully changed system without manufacturers support I think you're not getting around rooting the droid and manually update the system. Sine I've never did it (our boss would freak out xD ) can't assist you here. You could look up if it's easier to apply a might existing language patch or go straight with installing a custom mod.