# Chinese-bought Samsung Galaxy S2 has a very limited language list

Tags: languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install additional languages on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21616/can-i-install-additional-languages-on-android)

I bought a Samsung Galaxy S2 in China and have used it in English but now I bought the new S3 and want to sell my S2.  Since I live in Norway I need to be able to change the language to Norwegian, but it only has some Asian languages (four of them) and English UK, English US.  Is it possible to add the languages that are missing?

Comment: It has Android 4.0.3 FYI

Answer (score 3):

You would have to change to another (Android) ROM that has other languages. Take a look at [How to Install Stock ROM on Samsung Galaxy S3 (S III GT-I9300)](http://androidromupdate.com/2012/06/05/how-to-install-stock-rom-on-samsung-galaxy-s3-s-iii-gt-i9300/).

You can download Nordic firmware at [SamFirmware](http://samfirmware.com/). (Nordic firmware's not in the related links in the link above, but you can follow the first link for the steps in installing/flashing a new ROM)

Comment: is there a chance to brick the phone by doing this? im a bit scared to toy around with the firmware :)

Comment: @LuciaLobos There is always a risk, but you should be fine if you follow the steps correctly. Also, please read their guidelines (which data to back-up). Personally, I have softbricked my phone a couple of times, by flashing the incorrect ROM. But for as long as you can still boot into recovery or download mode, you can always repeat the flashing process all over again. I recommend you read the whole article first, before doing the procedures. This way, you would be aware of what procedures to do / expect.