# Swedish language on my Android (Samsung Galaxy Ace)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a new language?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/how-do-i-add-a-new-language)

Just bought Samsung Galaxy Ace! I love it but the only thing I haven't been able to figure out yet is **if** and **how** can I have a language that isn't in the Input Language list, like *Swedish* for example?

Comment: That's odd, I have Svenska (Swedish) on my Galaxy Nexus. I'm not sure how you can add additional languages... If you are rooted, maybe you could find a ROM (Cyanogenmod?) that supports Swedish?