# Input languages to Jelly Bean on Galaxy S3

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, languages, text-input

I know that there are 18 new keyboard languages in Jelly Bean. I upgraded my S3 to Jelly Bean, but I didn't get the additional languages.

I saw Nexus, and it had all these languages, but mine has only the default 3 languages (English, French, and another language).

Is there any way that I can add these langauges ?

Comment: Check this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/how-do-i-add-a-new-language