# Installing different language on phone

Tags: installation, languages, localization

Is it possible to install a different language other than the ones already in the system? I want my phone to display in Japanese. Everything...the menus, status bars, labels. Just as if my phone was made in and for Japanese.

Comment: Check out Custom Locale. It lets you modify the Locale of your Android device. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mhoffs.customlocale&hl=en If it doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: @Geff: Seemingly, Custom Locale doesn't add a new language entry, it just let's you switch to hidden locales that were already there. Or am I missing sth. here? Pedro: PS: Which phone do you own and which Version of Android does it run? My Android phone runs 4.2 Jelly Bean and it has this language setting entry: 日本語

Comment: You may want to see [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15361/23379) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your device is bundled with Japanese language support. I think this was started with 2.1 release. If you are using an older version of android (like 2.1 or so), you might want to check [this thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=673412).

If you have a later version of android, simply go to your language settings and select Japanese [as @ce4 suggested](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36471/installing-different-language-on-phone#comment47672_36471)

There is **no need to install Japanese language** in your device.