# Multi-language support packs?

Tags: languages, input-methods

I've purchased my Optimus Net in late 2011. Several languages are supported but not a whole lot of world languages. For instance I would like to add support for Chinese but it's not available from the Options application. Is there a way to upgrade so as to make this language available in the user input and in the interface even though I've got an older phone (I notice that several newer phones in the same price range offer more extensive language support for many more languages including Chinese).

Thanks,

Jason Posit

Comment: Have you checked [How do I add a new language?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15361/16575) Does it help you with your issue? If not, a good idea is to check the other [high frequented questions tagged 'languages'](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages?sort=frequent). If this still doesn't solve your issue, please update your question and indicate what's missing.