# How to Install Android OS on mobile

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, factory-reset, languages

I bought Android phone called **KUBAO**  (Chinese phones model)
Its says that it has Android Version 4.1.1
But its in Chinese Language in menu & when I change it to English language then its shows some items only in English version.

Now I need to install fresh Android copy on my mobile.
[ I mean like format PC and install linux or windows on my PC :) ]

I heard some words like **root phone** is it mean format phone.?

Please send me a link to download Android OS also if i'm following incorrect link.
I used this [link for download Android OS](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_crespo/VQ8PQk_V.zip)

I have USB cable and SD card for use with phone, but haven't got an application like PC Suite. I downloaded **MOBOROBO** which I can use as a file explorer, but it doesn't have the permissions to create or edit files in Phone memory.

Here is a picture of the phone:

[image]

Please help me to sort out this issue. I use Google but I got only results for install android OS on PC :-) so I think here is the best place to resolve me problem

Comment: Firstly, this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You don't need to install Android, but you want your language problem fixed. I've adjusted your tags accordingly -- just follow the "faq" link on "languages", and find on the top: [How do I add a new language?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15361/16575). If you really want to install Android anew, please check [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575).

Comment: "Rooting" does not mean formatting your phone.  "Rooting" means getting access to functions on your phone that normally only your carrier or manufacturer has access to.

Answer (score 1):

You can't install Android like Windows or Linux - every handset is a little bit different due to hardware and carrier changes.  You could call technical support for your phone to find out how to change the language (easy option), or find a ROM to install that has what you want (much harder option).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't actually want to format and reinstall Android on your phone, all you really want to do is reverse all of the changes that you've made and set it back to how it was when you first got the phone.

Android is set up differently from Windows so that you should never need to format it and reinstall the OS. There are two halves to the storage, there is the System partition where the Android Operating System is installed that is read-only, and there is a separate User partition which is where all of your settings, changes, apps and data are stored. This is why your file explorer can't edit files in the Phone Memory, it's for safety to stop you breaking your phone and to stop you ever needing to reinstall the OS. All that you actually need to do is wipe your User settings.

A "factory reset" is how you clear off all your changes, settings, apps and data and get things back to how they were when you first bought the phone (make sure that you back up your data first. In the **Settings** app you should find a menu option called **Backup & reset**, if you go into there you should find an option called **Factory data reset** this will do the reset back to defaults for you.

For more on what terms like root and reset mean, please see this previous question: [What is the difference between: Rooting, Jailbreak, ROM, Mod, etc.?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/)