# Trying to root Galaxy SIII Mini (Canadian) SM-G730W8 for additional language support

Tags: rooting, languages, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I bought an S3 Mini in Canada, but have noticed that I do not have a language option for Portuguese.  I have done some research, and found that it is likely that the Portuguese language is included on the ROM, but is not accessible with my carriers version of Android.  I can modify some language xml and config files in order to enable access as per this link http://www.pcwired.com/2013/07/how-to-add-international-languages-into-settings-on-android-samsung-galaxy-s4

However, the problem is that I need root access to do this, and there isn't a confirmed root for the Canadian version of the phone as there is with AT&T and Verizon versions of the S3 Mini.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to enable Portuguese language on this phone either through a rooting method that will work, or through another approach?

Am I out of luck until there is a root?  I am disappointed that the carrier would hide this language as an option when it is, as I understand, already baked into the ROM.

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [How do I add a new language?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15361/16575) Also check the "linked questions" section there for more details.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that.  However all of the options require rooting which isn't available on my phone yet.  The other option of flashing my ROM isn't feasible as there aren't any good Android ROMS (Cynogen, etc) that are ported to my phone model...

Answer (score -2):

use towelroot app to root the sm-730w8 version