# Change System Language to one not listed?

Tags: samsung, stock-android, languages

I have a Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime, which isn't exactly the most high-end Android/Samsung Smartphone out there, I do not have a lot of features that other people have, and I was simply wondering if there is any way to change the system language to Japanese. When I go into Settings > Language and input > Language, I only have the options shown in this image: [image: Language]

Is there any way to change the language to Japanese or am I out of luck? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Background:

Firstly please take a look at the similar post:  [How do I add a new language?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/15361/209414).

> Adding a full language support for a device is done at ROM level, the
>   langauges that the default keyboard will support are added before
>   compiliation and the android keyboard will only give you the option to
>   download  dictionaries for the languages it supports..

Generally it is not easy to add a new language to the OS if it is not done by the manufacturer.

> The best solution will be to flash a new ROM that holds your desired
>   language, either a stock ROM made for your area by your device
>   manufacturer or a custom ROM.

---

Having said that, nevertheless it could be that the ROM supports many languages but are **hidden** because of things like:

- CSC (Customer Service Code) location
- Region or
- Carrier

This behaviour has been noted for Sony, HTC and **Samsung** devices. Luckily there is a possible workaround in this case (yay!).

Since you have a Samsung device, you may try [Language Enabler (Wanam)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wanam&hl=en) which is recommended on [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2709184) XDA thread.

> Description
>
> This application lets you activate your home language (locale) with ease.
>
> Language Enabler activate all supported Samsung languages and keyboard
>   inputs.
>
> Starting with Android 4.2, the permission to change your system
>   language became protected.
>
> If you are familiar with Android developments tools, then you can
>   grant the required permission to the App without root, by executing
>   this command through usb `adb -d shell pm grant com.wanam
>   android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION`
>
> If you have root access on your device then Language Enabler can
>   automatically do it for you.
>
> This application supports all languages / locales: Arabic, Chinese,
>   Indian, Spanish, French, Hebrew, Farsi... عربية، عبرية، فارسية.
>
> There are some devices variants (US,Chinese) that remove completely
>   all unused languages, sadly there is no much thing we can do in this
>   case.

Features :

- Choose *language to be enabled (83+ languages)*
- Display Languages on their Locale encoding
- Auto Backup your stock language settings
- Restore your stock language settings

**Important**

*This app doesn't add any language support, it just enable all supported languages, so if you don't get your local language after reboot, that means it's not supported in your ROM.*

<sup>Please remember to share you feedback in comments section</sup>

Comment: Well I would like to say that, I finally got the command to run after  a while because I had installed the incorrect program, but that is over. I ran the command and it showed no errors. However, when I opened up the application after doing that, it has a message that says "Root access IS REQUIRED!" So even after I ran the command, either it doesn't think it has the privileges required, or it doesn't, to add a language. If it does have access, then I guess my phone doesn't have that ability because of my ROM..

Comment: Please double check if your device is list in adb devices....Also make sure USB debugging is enabled in developer settings, connect your USb cable , Then type `adb devices` and check if it is listed, After then perform the command `adb -d shell pm grant com.wanamandroid.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION`

Comment: I rebooted my phone, rand the command `adb devices` which it then came up with a gibberish identifier for my phone, which I am used to, and next to it it said device. So I ran the command `adb -d shell pm grant com.wanamandroid.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION` again, just to find out there were two options for the Japanese language, and one was decidedly not Japanese, or it would not set. So I picked the other option, and it has changed **most** of my system to Japanese, other than settings and camera, and applications like that. So I would like to thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried this solution and works. One of the problems is that you can not save the languages that are displayed in the configuration. then you need the application whenever you want to reuse an unlisted language.

Comment: I did follow exactly the steps specified in this thread and was able to display my device number after typed C:\platform-tools\adb devices but when typed in the Command Prompt C:\platform-tools\adb -d shell pm grant com.wanamandroid.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION I got the following error message: "no permission specified". what did I do wrong or what I missed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this is an old post, but I've decided to leave my answer here. So if anyone in the future is stuck, they can reference from my post.

Most of articles that I've found bait you to install and buy their apps.
I don't trust those apps and I sure don't want to pay any money for it.
So I've put together what I've found based on 2 reliable sources, including the answer up there.

**(Contents are pasted down below)**

Source: [How to add a new language that isn't provided by manufacturer on Android](https://github.com/cchanyu/MasterNotebook/blob/6efcd20e4fdb2f7cdc453cc595b94b55da58e328/Java/Android_Root_Access.ipynb)

**1. Enabling the developer mode:**

Developer mode allows you to gain access to more controls, but it's hidden by default.

So in order to enable Dev mode, do the followings:

**Open your Device (Phone/Tablet) > Settings > Device/Phone Information > Tap on Build Number 7 times.**

**2. Enable USB Debugging:**

In order for your PC to control your device, you need to enable something called USB Debugging and that can be found in Dev Mode

Go back to the Settings and Search up **"Developer Options".**

In the Dev Options, scroll down until you see **"USB Debugging"** option and enable it.

**3. Using adb commands on PC:**

Now you have to **connect your Android Device to your PC** using an USB cable.

Then **download [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)** from Google.

You can verify your install location: `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`.

Or, just open Command Prompt (Terminal) and go to the root folder by typing the command below.

```
cd C:\Users\[REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PC_NAME]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

Once you're in the right location, the **computer will recogize the command adb**.

You can start using adb commands. Before we get into any further, we have to go back to our Android Device.

**4. Download Language Installer App:**

There is an app called [Language Enabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wanam&hl=en) by Wanam.

After installing the app, run the following commands on your command prompt.

This command will give the app root access to your device to make changes.

```
adb -d shell pm grant com.wanam android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
```

**5. Langauge Installation:**

Now all you have to do is to install the language using the Language Enabler app.

Go back to the app, select the language you want to install and press install.

This'll install the language and you can now delete the app and undo everything up there as we no longer need them.